# Are there cost effective options for delivering a .NET winforms app as SAAS in 2017

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, azure

I have a winforms .NET app that has been under constant development for about 7 years. My clients are starting to require options for access as SAAS.

I have started developing my web platform, but this application is massive. It will take years before I can realistically offer the functionality without the winforms app. For the moment I just do the things that make sense on mobile.

In the interim, I am looking at being able to provide the application as SAAS. Ideally it would be great to deliver it without any client installation - e.g. through a browser, but I don't think that is possible. Other options are obviously Citrix Xenapp and the (now deprecated) MS RemoteApp. These are both a hell of a lot of overkill for me. I would at most have about 20 users on the system for the next 6 months and the cost/user would be awful. Not to mention that it seems that there is a lot to learn to set this up. Even the new Xenapp essentials costs about $25US/user by the time you add in the RDS CALS and the Virtual machine

I currently host my webapps (GUI - pure html/js, Data - WCF oData) and database (MSSQL) on azure.

Questions are;

1. Are there any better/alternative systems for offering SAAS with winforms than the Xenapp/Remoteapp for really small deploys like mine (it is very low on processor use too)
2. If I have to go the Xenapp path, are there any options that are not really complicated/expensive for this configuration.

Comment: Look at Adobe Creative Suite or Office 365 - they're both just subscription-licensed and download-delivered versions of otherwise "normal" formerly-boxed desktop software. The only real "cloud"/SaaS additions are online document hosting.

Comment: Also, you should avoid direct database connections over the Internet (e.g. from a desktop machine to an Azure SQL database) because database connection protocols all assume a low-latency, high-bandwidth connection (e.g. under 5ms ping) because they're very chatty. The recommendation is to expose your data services as web-services.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow - it can be seen as a tool/product recommendation question. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dai - I am aware of the issues with the db over network, but would have thought my question pretty clearly acknowledges this is a less-than-ideal stopgap while I get an alternative.

Comment: David - at some point we deploy our work. The deployment is just as important as the programming and manipulating the associated technologies is no less a programming question than the thousands of IDE related questions on stackoverflow. I am not after a product recommendation, just people's insight regarding potential solutions/technologies.